# Pop up results in windows under R

Tags: r, popup

After calculation I would like to pop up a windows displaying a message and the results. In the following example I would like to display in the pop up windows the value of x. The function winDialog seems to not be able to perform it.

```
library(sp)
library(svDialogs)
library(rgdal)

x <- runif(1, 1, 10)
if(x <= 5){
  winDialog("ok", "OK")
} else{
  winDialog("ok", "too big")
}
```

Comment: There's no need to include any external packages in the code as you're only using base R. You might want to delete the `library(...)` calls for better readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `paste()` to combine the value of your variable `x` and the text you want to print. Note that the `winDialog()` function only works under windows and not under other OS.

```
x <- runif(1, 1, 10)
winDialog("ok", paste(x, ifelse(x <= 5, "is OK", "is too big")))
```

[image: Dialog box]

Comment: Great. Is there a way to plot many variable (x, y, z...) in the same winDialog?

Comment: Sure, just add them to the `paste`. For example: `winDialog("ok", paste("variable x has value:", x, "and variable y has value:", y))`

Answer (score 0):

Here the code to pop-up a unique windows displaying different variable and each on a separate line:

```
library(svDialogs)
tolerance <- 13
X <- 62
Y <- 250.6587
Z <- 7
winDialog("ok", paste("Total number of points:", X, "                                        
Total surface (inch):", format(Y, digit=3),"
Number of points > tolerance:", Z))
```